# jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 external panel "push"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'am trying to implement the push function of panels.

In my app i have the following external panel:

```
<div data-role="panel" data-theme="a" id="navi-panel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay">
<ul data-role="listview" id="history"></ul>
</div>
```

I add dynamically listitmes to the listView and it works pretty fine. But when i change the data-display  value from **overlay** to **push** my whole application disappears. I tried it out with IE 8 and Chrome.

My JavaScript for init the panel is:

```
$(function() {
$("body>[data-role='panel']").panel().enhanceWithin();
}
```

****Note***:*

My JQM App is a single HTML-File size <= 800 kb.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This should solve your problem although I assume it was fixed in JQM 1.4.2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814211/jquery-mobile-handlebars-opening-a-panel-hides-the-data-role-content-div/20921033#20921033

Comment: thank you omar. The problem was, that i override the margin-top attribute of the whole page.