# jQuery Mobile External panels not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a frustrating issue.
According to the documentation, I am allowed to have external panels:

- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/panel-external/
- In the above example the header is inside the page, but the panels are **outside the page**

I am also allowed to have external headers and footers:

- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/toolbar-fixed-persistent/

Then logically I should be able to combine them:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
    <a href="#main_menu" data-transition="reveal" class="f-menu menu_control"><span>Open left panel</span></a>
    <h1>Info</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->


<div id="locale" data-role="page" data-title="Info" class="jqm-demos">

    <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth">
        <h1>LOCALE</h1>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<div id="privacy" data-role="page" data-title="Info" class="jqm-demos">

    <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth">
        <h1>PRIVACY</h1>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="panel" id="main_menu" data-position="left" data-display="reveal" data-theme="a">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="menu_contents">
        <li data-role="list-divider" class="h2 ui-li-divider ui-bar-a ui-first-child">
            <a href="#locale" data-transition="slide" data-rel="close" class="f-cogs">Page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" class="h2 ui-li-divider ui-bar-a ui-first-child">
            <a href="#privacy" data-transition="slide" data-rel="close" class="f-cogs">Page 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sidouglas/qVNyf/1/

As you will see in the fiddle, the sliding animation is not the same as ( http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/panel-external/ ). It's laggy and the height of the document is not being calculated correctly.

As per another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814211/jquery-mobile-handlebars-opening-a-panel-hides-the-data-role-content-div), I tried using `<div class="ui-panel-wrapper">` in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sidouglas/62SV2/). Still the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an old bug, from what I can see it wasn't fixed correctly.

Comment: I have reported a another bug: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7408 , strangely example works just fine on latest Chrome version but fails on previous one. Plus it works just fine in IE 10.0.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And here's a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8nM4u/

At least until this bug is solved, you should subscribe to bug report I left you in my comments on top.

Here's additional code you need for this to work correctly:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $("[data-role=panel]").one("panelbeforeopen", function () {
        var height = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage").outerHeight();
        $(".ui-panel-wrapper").css("height", height + 1);
    });
});
```

And say hi to [**Omar**](https://twitter.com/jQM_Tricks), he made you this solution. :)

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer.

Comment: Looks like it's still not fixed in 1.4.5. Thanks guys.